# How to get the icon/image of any file in java?

Tags: java, file, icons

i have a java.util.List filled with java.io.File and i wan't to list them in a gui. To display them i wan't to show their name which is accessable by the method getName() of java.io.File. And i want to display their icon/image with which they are displayed for example on the desktop. To build this i am using the newest javaversion (Java8/1.8). So far i found one way to do get the image of any file which looks like this:

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(pFile);
```

The problem about that is, that the returned icon is in a very small resolution(16x16) and i d like to display it in a bigger size. 80x80 would be perfect but doesn't have to be exactly it. 64x64 or smth like that would be fine, too. So i managed to resize the icon and stretch it but streatching 16x16 to 80x80 is not cool as you can imagine. There are to less pixels to get a good result.
I also found this tutorial but the first method shown in this tutorial doesn't work with Java8: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html The method i am using right now is copied from there.

So is there any way to get a bigger sized icon like the one which is shown on the desktop of a specific file?

Thanks
Baschdi

Comment: Just a comment... How about JFileChooser.getIcon(File) method, is it the same Icon with same size ?

Comment: @FerdinandNeman This method returns a generic icon. So for every file the same and for every directory the same. If you watch the tutorial it says that at then end and also shows the both icons. I want the actual icon of the specific file. So it its a programm like excel i want its specific excel-icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private BufferedImage getBufferedImage(final File pFile)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Image icon = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(pFile).getIcon(true);
    BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(icon.getWidth(null),
            icon.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = im.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(icon, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    int width = im.getWidth();
    int height = im.getHeight();
    System.out.println(width);
    System.out.println(height);
    final int maxHeigh = 79;
    double scaleValue = 0;
    if (height > width)
        scaleValue = maxHeigh / height;
    else
        scaleValue = maxHeigh / width;
    final int scaledWidth = (int) (im.getWidth() * scaleValue);
    final int scaledHeigh = (int) (im.getHeight() * scaleValue);
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeigh,
            im.getType());
    g = resized.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeigh, 0, 0, im.getWidth(),
            im.getHeight(), null);
    g.dispose();
    return resized;
}
```

I imported the jdk7 and used the older function with ShellFolder. Works fine, even when running on java8. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a library called JIconExtractReloaded which can extract all icons sizes not only 32x32. Here is the link https://github.com/MrMarnic/JIconExtractReloaded.

Just write:

```
BufferedImage image = JIconExtract.getIconForFile(128,128,"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");
```

And you have the icon.

Comment: You rock bro. You rock. Why don't you add support for macOS?

Comment: The library uses native windows libraries and therefore can’t work on MacOs

Comment: ooh. I see. Thank you for your support on the current one. Great work